# How do I make a function that takes in a radius of a circle and returns an array of points that draws a circle in OpenGL coordinantes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, geometry

I have a function that draws me a circle in canvas coordinates but I can't find a way for me to convert those coordinates into webgl coordinates. Here's my function:

```
function circlearray(diameter, accuracy) {
    const circle = [];
    let theta = 0;
    let dtheta = (2 * Math.PI) / accuracy;

    for (let i = 0; i < accuracy; i++) {
        circle.push([Math.cos(theta) * diameter, Math.sin(theta) * diameter]);
        theta += dtheta;
    }

    return circle;
}
```

accuracy is basically a way to tell the function to draw a set number of points (for performance or precision reasons)

I tried to convert the canvas coordinates into webgl coordinates but I couldn't find an accurate way :(

Comment: NDC space is -1 to 1 so if your "*diameter*" (which really is *radius*) is supposed to be pixels then you'll have to divide by `canvas.width / 2` and `canvas.height / 2` respectively.